# Open link in new tab from pop-up using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to open up a new page using a link in a pop-up in a new tab. I am new to Jquery so I am unsure if this is on the correct track:

```
 $('.modal-content a').click(function() {
      alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
      a.set('target', '_blank');
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div>
        <h1>This is  pop-up</h1>
    </div>
<p><a href="www.google.co.nz">Open in new window</a></p>
</div>
```

"modal-content" is the class name of the pop-up div. I am not sure if I am calling the link element correctly. There is no unique identifier on the  tag.

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

```
$('a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

or
[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop)

```
$('a').prop('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: That alert is not firing at all. So I am guessing that I am not selecting the element correctly.